# Add Dynamic Content - Azure Data Factory ADF

Tags: azure, expression, azure-data-factory

I need to add a Dynamic Content in an ADF. In such a way that it needs to get last month date as below formate.

Result: 2018-12.csv.zip

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Above given case works, if I know the date but I am running my Data Factory every day. So below works better.

@concat(substring(string(if(equals(int(formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'MM')),01), sub(int(formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyyMM')),89),sub(int(formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyyMM')),1))),0,4),'-',substring(string(if(equals(int(formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'MM')),01), sub(int(formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyyMM')),89),sub(int(formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyyMM')),1))),4,2),'.csv.zip')

Any changes appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the date to the 28th and then subtract 30 days, that should get you into the previous month from any date.  Then simply format as `yyyy-MM`, eg

`@concat(formatDateTime(adddays(formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyy-MM-28'),-30),'yyyy-MM'),'.csv.zip')`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions.

Possible solution: 
I will suggest you to use 3 parameters here. 
 This solution use trigger().startTime, but you can use utcnow() aswell.

Note: adddays(trigger().startTime,-31,'MM') will return 12 as month, as that month was 31 days ago. If your trigger is on 5th of the month, or on the first day in the month than you can use -2.

```
processYear = @formatDateTime(adddays(trigger().startTime,-31), 'yyyy')

processMonth = @formatDateTime(adddays(trigger().startTime,-31), 'MM')

result = @concat(pipeline().parameters.processYear,'-',pipeline().parameters.processMonth,'.csv.zip').
```

Hope that this helps.

Comment: If we make '-31' days then If I run on March 1st. the date goes to Jan Month as Feb has only max 29 days. Need to change the solution.

Comment: it depends when you run your pipeline. 
If you run it on every second day of the month then you can put '-3' etc.
I put -31 as an example for January if you want to get 201812

Answer (score 0):

@concat(formatDateTime(subtractFromTime(utcNow(),1,'Month'), 'yyyy-MM'), '.csv.zip')